# Unable to fetch modify data in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I did not get a good answer for my previous question. In this question I provide more thing but still not get proper result.. anyone help me...

```
1st row amount=1200, 
2nd row amount=1320(1200+120),
3rd row amount=1452(1320+132)
```

Logic is 10% add with previous amount

```
;WITH nums AS
   (SELECT 1 AS RowNum, 1200 AS value
    )

    SELECT RowNum, Value
FROM nums
```

Results:

```
   Sno - Name- Amount
    1  - A  -  1200
```

Now I want result like this..

```
Sno - Name- Amount
1  - A  -  1200
2  - A  -  1320
3  - A  -  1452
```

Can anybody help me I'm not find any logic for that in same query no external table create or implement

Comment: Sorry: *what* ?!?!? This makes no sense whatsoever.... you need to rephrase this question and explain better what you're trying to achieve....

Comment: i'm not get answer still now @marc_s

Comment: ^yup, exact duplicate from same user

Answer (score 0):

I come from Oracle background; but I hope this helps as it works for me in Oracle:

```
WITH nums(rn, value) AS
(
  SELECT ROWNUM rn, 1200 AS value FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rn + 1 rn, round(value * 1.1) FROM nums
  where rn < 100
)
SELECT RowNum, Value
FROM nums
```

It generates up to 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like this :

```
WITH nums(rn, value) AS
(
  SELECT 1 rn, 1200 AS value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rn + 1 rn, value + round(value/10,2) as value
  FROM nums
  where rn < 10
)
SELECT rn, Value
FROM nums
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25850)**